# Inserting 2 delimited strings into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a simple select statement that can take a string of prodcodes from a table called WCvsNIRTemps and show them in individual rows.

```
SELECT 
Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS ProdCodes 
FROM  (SELECT   
CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([ProdCodes], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String
FROM  WCvsNIRTemps where TemplateName = 'TempName') AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

How can I go about showing two columns of data? The delimited string contains the correct order for both of them. So the first listed prodcode ties to the first item listed in the new column prodnam which I'd like to show. Perhaps a pivot table would be a smart idea. Here is my attempt.

```
SELECT 
Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS ProdCodes, Split2.b.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS ProdNams 
FROM  (SELECT   
CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([ProdCodes], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String
FROM  WCvsNIRTemps where TemplateName = 'TempName') AS A 
 CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a),
(SELECT   
CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([ProdNams], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String
FROM  WCvsNIRTemps where TemplateName = 'TempName') AS B
 CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split2(b)
```

WCvsNIRtemps Table:

```
**TemplateName  |  ProdCodes             |  Prodnams**
TempName           prodc1,prodc2,prodc3     prodn1,prodn2,prodn3
```

Desired Query Output:

```
**Prodcode |  Prodnam**
prodc1        prodn1
prodc2        prodn2
prodc3        prodn3
```

Comment: Search "rows to columns". You will find the word PIVOT.

Answer (score 0):

Try below, it will help you :

```
    ;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT   M.N.value('.[1]','VARCHAR(8000)') AS PRODUCT_CODES, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by M.N.value('.[1]','VARCHAR(8000)') ASC) as Prod_ID,
    P.Q.value('.[1]','VARCHAR(8000)') AS PRODUCT_NAMES, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by P.Q.value('.[1]','VARCHAR(8000)') ASC) as ProdName_ID
    FROM
    (
     SELECT CAST('<XMLROOT><ROWDATA>' + REPLACE(PRODCODES,',','</ROWDATA><ROWDATA>') + '</ROWDATA></XMLROOT>' AS XML) AS X,
     CAST('<XMLROOT><ROWDATA>' + REPLACE(PRODNAMS,',','</ROWDATA><ROWDATA>') + '</ROWDATA></XMLROOT>' AS XML) AS Y          
     FROM   TEMPTABLE
    )T
    CROSS APPLY X.nodes('/XMLROOT/ROWDATA')M(N)
    CROSS APPLY Y.nodes('/XMLROOT/ROWDATA')P(Q))
    SELECT DISTINCT A.PRODUCT_CODES,B.PRODUCT_NAMES FROM CTE A INNER JOIN CTE B
    ON A.PROD_ID=B.PRODNAME_ID ORDER BY A.PRODUCT_CODES
```

It will give below output :

[image: delimited_string_to_sql]

I hope this help. I would like to thanks my friend Bhushan for helping me in this.

Comment: I am not sure why output image is not showing, but output is same as mentioned in question.